# Autofixture - base property in new list on property from a previously constructed one

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, testing, autofixture

I think I'm missing something, but what I'm trying to do is this:

I have two database entities represented in my C# code. One is a child of the other, therefore the child contains a field which should reference the parent's ID.

The parent class is the following

```
public class Product
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public decimal DeliveryPrice { get; set; }
}
```

The child class is the following:

```
public class ProductOption
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I have created a list of random "parents" as such:

```
var products = fixture.CreateMany<Product>(5).ToList();
```

What I wanted to do was then create 10 child objects, and randomly give them a `ProductId` from the list of products created by AutoFixture. So I tried this:

```
var rand = new Random();
var options = fixture.Build<ProductOption>()
    .With(option => option.ProductId, products[rand.Next(0, 5)].Id)
    .CreateMany(10)
    .ToList();
```

It *almost* worked, but what I found was that all the `ProductId`s were the same one, so it obviously only ever hit `rand.Next` once.

Is what I'm doing even possible/advisable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I provide value for the property, I would expect all instances build with same builder/fixture will have provided value.
So what you noticed is desired behaviour.

Instead of already generated value you can provide a "factory" which will generate value for the property during instance creation.
Latest Autofixture version introduced overload for `.With` method which accepts a function as parameter.

```
var rand = new Random();
Func<Guid> pickProductId = () => products[rand.Next(0, 5)].Id;

var options = 
    fixture.Build<ProductOption>()
           .With(option => option.ProductId, pickProductId)
           .CreateMany(10)
           .ToList();

// Prove
options.Select(o => o.ProductId).ToHashSet().Should().HaveCountGreaterThan(1); // Pass Ok
```

Comment: Ah yes, I was looking through the intellisense overloads but I got a little confused. This actually makes perfect sense, a function that serves as a "generator"

Thank you!